# Angular 4 web page doesn't redirect by <a href>

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have angular 4 web application. This application just contains the followig hyperlink: 
[Click on me](http://www.google.com). Then I put ng serve in bash command. After that, I go to Firefox last version 64 bits and I put manually the url http://localhost:4200. I see the hyperlink but when I click it, it doesn't redirect to Google. It keeps in http ://localhost:4200. When I click after 3 times, it redirects to Google. I tried to delete cache/cookies/etc, then I restarted Firefox and I repeated the test and happens the same.

It just occurs in Firefox. In IE and Chrome works well.

I also realized it happens under ng serve/webpack-dev-server but if I deploy the angular application into another web server such as Apache/Tomcat, it works well on Firefox, I mean it redirects to google.

My two questions are Why is it happening and What can I do?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that might be causing this? Also, did you try this with a clean install of Firefox?

Comment: I'm using Firefox version 54 (64 bits). I use jquery, tether, bootstrap, external lib for wysiwyg, I don't think wysiwyg is the problem. Another way I see to make it works in Firefox is uninstalling and installing Firefox but it takes effect in a few days. Sometimes support technician does windows update, antivirus update to my PC but I don't know if this is a possible reason.

Comment: Did you try the same scenario with private browsing? That might be easier to try.

Comment: I tested with private browsing but happens the same. I'm thinking maybe is Firefox configuration (about:config) o some way to configure webpack-dev-server